# jQuery event delegation not working for some buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, blueimp, jquery-events, event-delegation

I am using the jQuery file upload plugin called `bluimp`. My 2 buttons (`start`, `cancel`) are forming dynamically so I can't attach a event listener to them. I have attached a listener to their nearest static ancestor, i.e. a form with an Id of `fileupload`. `delete` is formed after successful upload via `start` button.

The `delete` button listener is working but not the `start` one. (I am talking about my custom listeners for both buttons to do additional actions. The default actions supplied by `blueimp` are working fine.)

The code snippets:

**html** (dynamically generated button html)

```
<td>
    <button id="start-upload-button" class="btn btn-primary start">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
        <span>Start</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
        <span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

After `start` is clicked and uploading is done `delete`'s html is formed

```
<button id="file-delete-button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="POST" data-url="/delete/25">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <span>Delete</span>
</button>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').on("click", "#file-delete-button", function(event) {
        console.log("Delete event fired");
        $("#sourcetext").hide();
    });

    $('#fileupload').on("click", "#start-upload-button", function(event) {
        console.log("Upload event fired");
        $("#sourcetext").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: you say, `start` creates `delete`, but `delete` is working fine and `start` isn't. how does `delete` appear then?

Comment: My listener on `start` is not working. `start`  is working as intended and the behaviour borrowed from `blueimp` and I have not written any custom behaviour. So the formation of `delete` is handled by `blueimp`.
 I just want to do additional actions upon clicking of `start` which `blueimp` doesn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should follow [manual](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options)  to bind callbacks to your buttons

```
$("#fileupload").bind('fileuploadstart', function(e){
     console.log("Upload event fired");  
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have followed the manual. I got confused because I didn't see the same behaviour with the 2 buttons with my approach. Anyways thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, i've never read about blueimp but it looks interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `on` function. The `bind` event is deprecated.

```
$(document).on('fileuploadstart', '#fileupload',function(e){
     console.log("Upload event fired");  
});
```

This will guarantee the binding in elements even if the element was auto generated.